# Integración de notificaciones push en aplicaciones MAUI .NET 7

Tags: .net, maui

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación multiplataforma utilizando MAUI .NET 7 y estoy buscando información sobre cómo integrar notificaciones push en mi aplicación. Sin embargo, he notado que la mayoría de las soluciones y tutoriales disponibles son para .NET 6 o versiones anteriores.

Me gustaría recibir orientación específica sobre cómo implementar notificaciones push en aplicaciones MAUI .NET 7, ya sea utilizando Firebase, Azure Notification Hubs u otras herramientas. Es importante destacar que necesito información actualizada y compatible con MAUI .NET 7, ya que las soluciones anteriores parecen no ser compatibles o presentar problemas en esta versión.

Agradecería cualquier ejemplo de código, documentación o tutorial que me puedan proporcionar, especialmente enfocado en MAUI .NET 7. ¡Gracias!